# How to enable Oracle Database In-Memory feature in Oracle 11g R2 to reduce report generation time?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, memory-optimized-tables, in-memory-database

**Problem:**
Each report generation takes a few hours in Oracle 11g R2 and a few tens of reports has to be generated every day.

**Objective:**
To reduce report generation time

**Understood:**
a) "reports that used to take hours can now be executed in seconds using oracle in-memory database feature".
(Reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/database/oracle-database-18c-%3a-now-available-on-the-oracle-cloud-and-oracle-engineered-systems?elq_mid=104407&sh=26961462026142651578242315&cmid=WWMK170418P00047)
b) The feature is introduced in Oracle 12c and is available in its later versions.

**Please advise on:**
a) how in-memory/cache table feature of 11g and database in-memory of 12c are related? former one can be used to improve report generation performance?
b) Procedure to enable the in-memory database feature in Oracle 11g R2?
c) Procedure to make standby database of 11g to 12c?

Comment: These are different features: in 11g you can cache a table with row based format using DB_KEEP_CACHE_SIZE parameter. but the in-memory feature in 12c uses of column format to store data in the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) + b) The In-Memory Column Store option was introduced in version 12.1.0.2, it is not available in 11g.

[Changes in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/release_changes.htm#GUID-7CFB8977-7183-4EEA-BA1A-100B7B1989C2)

You can cache tables in earlier versions as well, but the new In-Memory option is different. The point of the new In-Memory option is it stores tables in memory in columnar format, instead of the default row level format.

c) Logical standy, Goldengate (requires extra licence) or Streams.